# Testing Akka Streams divertTo with streams testkit

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-testkit

I have a graph composed of several flows, each of which returns an `Either` of some error or the actual result. The code is using [`divertTo`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/divertTo.html) in order to send any `Lefts` to a different sink than the happy-path downstream sink.

The problem I am having is that when using the Akka Streams testkit, I can't find a way to probe the sink used in the `divertTo` call. I can probe the happy-path sink fine but I really need to find a way to test the not-so-happy paths to prove that my flow is working.

Has anybody done this type of thing before using the streams testkit?

Comment: Please edit your question to include any code you've already tried, and then [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I am having is that...I can't find a way to probe the sink used in the `divertTo` call....Has anybody done this type of thing before using the streams testkit?

Yes:
https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.5/akka-stream-tests/src/test/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/GraphPartitionSpec.scala

From the above spec:

```
"divertTo must send matching elements to the sink" in assertAllStagesStopped {
  val odd = TestSubscriber.probe[Int]()
  val even = TestSubscriber.probe[Int]()
  Source(1 to 2).divertTo(Sink.fromSubscriber(odd), _ % 2 != 0).to(Sink.fromSubscriber(even)).run()
  even.request(1)
  even.expectNoMessage(1.second)
  odd.request(1)
  odd.expectNext(1)
  even.expectNext(2)
  odd.expectComplete()
  even.expectComplete()
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I should have checked the tests to begin with.